# Robot Framework UI Test Fails Due to CSRF

Tags: robotframework

Recently our devs implemented a CSRF protection, and then my scripts (web ui) started to fail one by one. I looked into it and it's getting this error on console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://url.com' (redirected from 'url') from origin 'https://url.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

any idea how to get around with this?

Comment: Why don't you disable CSRF protection in the test enviorments?

Comment: For some reason, "they" won't allow that to happen so the choice is to disable the test or find a workaround

Comment: If you can't find a way, I would suggest contacting people with better influence. "for some reason" is what kids know about why their parents make decisions they don't like, it's not an acceptable discourse between professionals.

Comment: what step you are trying to do that throws this error ? are you trying to execute some javascript request from your test script ?